# How do unify chars in only one char using sprintf Arduino IDLE

Tags: c++, char

I have a problem because I tried to unify 3 chars in only one for send through Xbbe use a Waspmote IDLE that is similar that Arduino.The data that save in the char are float
When I use the function sprintf to unify the char,the answer is only a ? symbol.

Share the code for you help,because I didnt know that I do bad.

Thank you

```
char envio[60];
char envio_x[15];
char envio_y[15];
char envio_z[15];
const int eje_x=ANALOG5;
const int eje_y=ANALOG3;
const int eje_z=ANALOG1;
void setup()
{

xbee802.init(XBEE_802_15_4,FREQ2_4G,NORMAL);


 xbee802.ON(); // starts using the serial port
   USB.begin();
  PWR.setSensorPower(SENS_5V,SENS_ON);

  pinMode(eje_x,INPUT);
  pinMode(eje_y,INPUT);
  pinMode(eje_z,INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
int x=analogRead(eje_x);
int y=analogRead(eje_y);
int z=analogRead(eje_z);
float zeroG=430.0;
float scale=93.0;
float outx=((float)x-zeroG)/scale;
float outy=((float)y-zeroG)/scale;
float outz=((float)z-zeroG)/scale;
dtostrf(outx,5,5,envio_x);
dtostrf(outy,5,5,envio_y);
dtostrf(outz,5,5,envio_z);

 // Utils.setLED(LED0,LED_ON);

sprintf(envio,"x:%f y:%f z:%f \n",envio_x,envio_y,envio_z,'\n',"\r");
xbee802.send("0013A20040691665",envio);

// Utils.setLED(LED0,LED_ON);
  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: It’s hard to tell what you want to say. Your `sprintf` call uses `%f` which requires `float` arguments, but you provide `char` arguments. You also have 2 (`'\n',"\r"`) superfluous arguments at the end.

Comment: In general I need to do a char with this three float, but I use `dtostf` for convert the float in char and later use `sprintnf` to combine in char dor later send

Comment: I can’t understand you. You want to combine 3 values into 1 `char`? If so, a `char` has 8 bits, not a lot of space to fit 3 values in, but you usually do this with bit shifting.

Comment: Use `%s` in your sprintf format string. `dtostrf` creates a string. `outx` and friends should also be doubles, not floats. http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html

Comment: `sprintf(envio,"x:%f y:%f z:%f \n",envio_x,envio_y,envio_z,'\n',"\r");`: The last two arguments `,'\n',"\r"` are not addressed in the format string. (It has only three `%` formatters.) These will be silently ignored. This is not an error as you can add as many extra arguments as you like. However, if this was intentional you probably should read the doc. about [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) again... (Or your libary provides a crazy specific non-standard version of `sprintf()` what I struggle to believe.)